# Can this be a periodic function

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, periodic-functions

$$F(x) = \sqrt{\sin x + \cos x}$$
I graphed this function and it seemed to be periodic but my textbook says that it's not. 
Is  any other rule it's breaking...?

Comment: You say you graphed this function: with $\;x\;$ ranging **on what interval(s)** ?

Comment: I graphed it in no specific interval

Comment: How can you possibly graph a function «in no specified interval»?

Comment: I mean just from - infinity to + infinity

Comment: It is a function of a periodic function. Must be periodic.

Comment: @Sudhanshu That can't be: there are points where $\;\sin x+\cos x<0\;$ and thus its square root isn't defined as real function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is periodic with period $2\pi$. Indeed, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both periodic with period $2\pi$. (Technically, this only shows that $F(x)$ is either constant or periodic with period $2\pi/n$ for some $n$, but in this case the period is exactly $2\pi$.)

Comment: Is it OK that the function is not defined for some x..

Comment: That's up to you. You can say that when $\sin x + \cos x < 0$, the function is undefined, and this gives you a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \bot \}$, where $\bot$ stands for undefined. This function is periodic. Or you could choose a branch of the (complex) square root function, and this gives you a periodic function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. In any case, as long as you're consistent, the function is periodic.

Comment: Another option is to think of $F$ as a function $\{x \colon \sin(x) + \cos(x) \geq 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$. In this case, you have to explain what you mean by "periodic" for a function whose domain is not all of $\mathbb{R}$. Presumably you mean that the domain *itself* is periodic, and the function is periodic, with a common period. This is equivalent to the first option above.